# How to unload OCaml plugin?

Tags: ocaml, dynamic-linking

I want to write a program that

1. Reads user input.
2. Interprets it as OCaml source code and writes it into a temporary `.ml` file.
3. Compiles the file into a module, plugin or whatever.
4. Links the resulting object using `Dynlink.loadfile`.
5. Unloads the no more needed code from memory.

I managed to sort out first 4 steps:

```
open Core.Std

let () =
  let prog = read_line () in
  let oc = Out_channel.create "tmp.ml" in

  fprintf oc "%s" prog;
  Out_channel.close oc;

  Unix.waitpid_exn (Unix.fork_exec ~prog:"ocamlopt"
    ~args:["-c"; "-shared"; "-o"; "tmp.cmxs"; "tmp.ml"] ~use_path:true ());

  Dynlink.loadfile "tmp.cmxs"
```

When watching this program execute with `top`, I noticed, quite obviously, that the used memory increases after the load. If I repeat this in a loop this may end badly.

Is it even possible to  unload the code from memory? Or maybe it will be done automatically when the garbage collector sees I have no bindings to the loaded objects?

Comment: You might be able to do something clever by having the dynlink set a value as a module in an option, then you could set that value to None after. I think that would be the only way to "unload", but it's not really what you want.

Comment: btw, see the `ocaml_plugin` (https://github.com/janestreet/ocaml_plugin) project as it does some of this for you, and you may gain some inspiration.

Comment: @nlucaroni Could you give a more detailed explanation of that option thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it is impossible to unload the code. Of course, you can take precautions and unload any data structures, that was created by your module as a side-effect, as soon as they are no longer needed.

But code can't be removed, since it is is stored in the code fragments table, that is never freed.

If you want to dynamically evaluate code, then I would suggest you to use `compiler-libs`, for example this will evaluate an expression for you:

```
open Core_kernel.Std
open Or_error

let eval_exn str =
  let lexbuf = Lexing.from_string str in
  let phrase = !Toploop.parse_toplevel_phrase lexbuf in
  Toploop.execute_phrase false Format.err_formatter phrase

let eval str = try_with (fun () -> eval_exn str)
```

Comment: You say it like it is a general rule going beyond OCaml. Does it mean that all those applications supporting plugins, e.g. web browsers, don't unload a disabled plugin until they are themselves terminated?

Comment: oh, ho. I was taking only about OCaml, consulting to its current implementation. Applications in other languages, usually loaded plugins using `dlopen`, so they use dynamic linking.

Comment: Actually in a native mode dynlink also uses a `dlopen`, but we still have no possibility to unload it.

Comment: Could it be implemented eventually or is it inherently impossible?

Comment: It could be implemented, especially in a native mode. If you really want to load/unload plugins, then you can try to not to use ocaml's dynlink, but load them directly with dlopen. OCaml ctypes provides an interface to it. Or you can call it directly. In that case you need to compile your code to *.so (or *.dll or *.dlyb), and load it as any other native code.

Comment: It's not precisely what's being asked for, but there is a proposal available for making the OCaml runtime unloadable: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/71 - this may be usable/extendable to support unloading dynlink'd code.